# Qemu terminating on signal x from pid xxxx

Tags: kvm, qemu

I've been all over google and back and I cannot locate any information on this particular error.

**qemu: terminating on signal 15 from pid 3111**

I'm using Virtualizor to launch new **KVM** VPS on my machines. I am getting this error in my vps startup logs that's preventing the system from working.

```
2012-01-05 18:38:14.927: starting up
LC_ALL=C PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -S -M rhel6.2.0 -enable-kvm -m 1024 -smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threa
ds=1 -name 1001 -uuid 81658116-8f37-4939-829a-c679c3576b00 -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/1001.monit
or,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -drive file=/dev/vg_hv2/vs1001,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,fo
rmat=raw,cache=none -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=23,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev
=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=00:16:3e:46:da:e1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -usb -vnc 198.1
45.30.132:1,password -k en-us -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
char device redirected to /dev/pts/0
qemu: terminating on signal 15 from pid 3111
2012-01-06 04:06:20.875: shutting down
2012-01-06 05:07:21.782: starting up
```

This is an example of my startup logs for the vps that I just tried to create. Notice the qemu terminating error, then the system restarts and tries this same sequence three more times until finally failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! It was super simple. Just required that I install the operating system templates on the master as well as the slave. Once done the vps' all created just fine.

Thanks @shawn for providing a link

http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/how-you-can-use-qemukvm-base-images-be-more-productive-part-1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the operating system templates on the master.

http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/how-you-can-use-qemukvm-base-images-be-more-productive-part-1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

this message means qemu was killed by another process. run `ps -ef |grep 3111` to find out what that process is.